# How can I contribute to existing marketplace module

Tags: module, sitecore-marketplace

I have used this module [Sitecore CDN Connector](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_CDN_Connector.aspx?sc_lang=en) before and now updated it for Sitecore 8.1 and 8.2

How can I upload the new package to the marketplace? Do I need to add this as a new module?

Ideally, it's better to update the existing one. Is there a way to do that?

Update: I am not the author of the original module.

Comment: Are you the author of the original package?

Comment: No, I am not the author of original one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't directly update someone else's package. You need to be added as a contributor to that package. I would follow these steps:

### Update source and create a pull request

As you have found, the source for the project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/NTTDATA/SitecoreCDN). You can update that and make a pull request. At the same time you can request the author update the package on the marketplace.

### Locate the author on Sitecore Slack

The package says that NTT Data in the author of the package with a single checkin by Anton Setiadi. Using [Sitecore Slack](https://www.akshaysura.com/2015/10/27/how-to-join-sitecore-slack-community-chat/) you can reach out to the authors and ask to be added as a contributor.

With quick scan of Linked In, I have found several users that work at NTT and also are on Sitecore Slack. You just need to locate the original author and then get authorized to update it.